# Struggling with the rxjs `merge` interface

Tags: typescript, rxjs, typescript-generics

I have an issue with the RxJs merge interface:

```
export function merge<A extends readonly unknown[]>(...sources: [...ObservableInputTuple<A>]): Observable<A[number]>;
```

So, based on this I created the following

```
const a$ = of('a').pipe(delay(1000));
const b$ = of('b');
const c$ = of('c').pipe(delay(10));

const y = merge<string[]>(d$, e$, f$) as Observable<string[number]>;
```

Nothing is complaining here. But when I use a little bit more complex interface

```
interface Foo<A = unknown, B = { id: string}> {
    input: A;
    output?: B;
} 

const a$ = of({input: 'a'}).pipe(delay(1000));
const b$ = of({input: 'b'});
const c$ = of({input: 'c'}).pipe(delay(10));

const x = merge<Foo<string>[]>(a$, b$, c$) as Observable<Foo<string>[number]>;
```

It complains about `number`

> Type 'Foo<string, { id: string; }>' has no matching index signature for type 'number'.
> [image]

I must do something wrong here, any suggestions what my mistake is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `merge` will combine all observable into one, so the return type a union of all types.

In your first case : `Observable<string>`

and your second one : `Observable<{input: string}>`

And no need to specify the generic, the compiler can infer the type itself.

---

Lets decompose the type :

```
export function merge<A extends readonly unknown[]>(...sources: [...ObservableInputTuple<A>]): Observable<A[number]>;
```

`A` is generic with a constraint of `Array<unknown>`.

Knowing `A`, `A[number]` means every type of the array type `A`.

This means with `Foo = [string, number];`, `Foo[number]` equals `string | number`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was already close, but your answer gave me the last push I needed :)